# How do I create a triangular prism like the image below in tikz for latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I would like to not have it colored but rather just the green shaded be dark grey shaded. Could someone please help me with this? I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: This post could be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595056/how-can-i-write-an-isosceles-triangular-prism-in-latex

Comment: @stefan-pinnow The answer given by user ABC is much better than the answer on the question you refer to. Code is much shorter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a rather unsophisticated way of drawing such things.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,
    declare function={b=3;h=2;l=4;}]
 \draw[dashed] (-b/2,-l/2,0) -- (-b/2,l/2,0) edge (b/2,l/2,0) -- (0,l/2,h);     
 \draw (b/2,l/2,0) -- (0,l/2,h) -- (0,-l/2,h);
 \draw[fill=gray,fill opacity=0.3] (b/2,-l/2,0)  -- (0,-l/2,h) -- (-b/2,-l/2,0);
 \draw[blue] (b/2,-l/2,0)  -- node[below] {$\ell$} (b/2,l/2,0);
 \draw[green!70!black] (b/2,-l/2,0)  -- node[below] {$b$}  (-b/2,-l/2,0);
 \draw[red] (0,-l/2,0)  -- node[left] {$h$} (0,-l/2,h);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by unsophisticated?

Comment: I like the idea using a function to draw this. This way you can nicely adjust h, b or l. Therefore, I don't think it is unsophisticated at all!

Comment: @JasperHabicht ABC is a humble wizard....